# acts-as-votable : Get an array of voters with names and date of voting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-votable

How to get the list of user names that voted for a post, including their id and date of vote ?

Here is my (working) solution....

```
voters = []
item.votes_for.each do |vote|
    voters << { updated_at: vote.updated_at, voter_id: vote.voter_id, voter_name: User.find(vote.voter_id).name }
end
json.voters voters
json.up_votes voters.count
```

I found that far from optimal... Especially because of the addtional query to User.find(...) which can lead to multiple queries when there is a lot of votes.

Is there a more "railsy" way to implement that ?

item.votes_for.voters provides a link to the user Model, but there is no acces to the date of vote if I do that....

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your mode for `User` and `Vote` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to include the voters in your votes when you request them.

```
voters = item.votes_for.includes(:voter).map do |vote|
     { updated_at: vote.updated_at, voter_id: vote.voter_id, voter_name: vote.voter.name }
end
```

Comment: And `map` can be used to avoid appending to the Array

Comment: Great :-) It works fine :-) I've learned "includes" and also the .map thing to remove the "<<". Thanks to both of you.